# None of Material UI Typography elements are vertically aligned

Tags: css, material-ui

I am using Material UI with React and wherever I put `<Typography>` element it gives itself too much height or it is not vertically aligning text inside of it properly. Here are some pictures as examples:

[image]

[image]

Here is a usage example from one of my screens:

```
<Typography onClick={() => _redirect("/")} variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
    Boardee
</Typography>
```

`classes.title` only has a `cursor: pointer` inside of it.

It is a pretty weird "error". Not sure what to do with it.

Comment: When you say "it gives itself too much height" and "it is not vertically aligning text inside of it properly" it isn't clear what you are expecting it to do. What do you think it would look like if it was doing it "properly"?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I want the blue box(its container) to either be smaller so that there is no extra useless space at the bottom or to center the text inside of that blue box

Comment: It would help if you created a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that demonstrates the undesirable behavior. Currently you are showing the code for a single `Typography` element which doesn't give any indication of what code you are using for the other elements that you are comparing its alignment to.